# Word list for Common European Framework of Reference for Languages (CEFR)

Tags: data-request, language

The Common European Framework of Reference for Languages: Learning, Teaching, Assessment, abbreviated as [CEFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages), is a guideline used to describe achievements of learners of foreign languages across Europe. While the CEFR describes what a learner is supposed to be able to do in reading, listening, speaking and writing at each level, it appears that there are word lists that are relevant for each level.

Are these word lists available as open data? Especially, I am interested in Spanish A1 vocabulary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [Wictionary list for Spanish A1 vocabulary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Spanisch/Grundwortschatz) that would be easy to parse in the [print version](https://de.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Verzeichnis:Spanisch/Grundwortschatz&printable=yes).

Answer (score 4):

[Here's a PDF](http://www.euralex.org/elx_proceedings/Euralex2012/pp328-335%20Marello.pdf) with some of the Spanish words, should be fairly easy to extract them:

See also this English list as an example:

http://cambridgeenglish.org/images/22105-ket-vocabulary-list.pdf -

Also, it appears you might have to request the list as explained at the bottom of this page:

http://coe.int/t/dg4/linguistic/dnr_EN.asp

Comment: Thank you, very interesting. It is a pity that the spanish word list is only an example with less then 20 words..